# Django two-way relationship between group and group members

Tags: django, models

I am trying to model a two-way relationship between group members and the group they belong to.

More specifically, I'd like to model something like this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    my_group = models.ForeignKey('Group')
    #leader = models.BooleanField()

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    leader = models.ForeignKey('Member')
```

So I want every member to be linked to a group. But each group should have a leader. I'd normally add a "leader" attribute to assign a leader for a group or add an extra model / table. However, I would like to be able to choose the leader from the members list for a specific group in the Django Admin interface and the above attempt results in an error of course, because the two models reference each other.

Here's the error:

```
ERRORS: app1.Group.leader: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Group.leader' clashes with field name 'Member.my_group'. HINT: Rename field 'Member.my_group', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Group.leader'
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: can an user be in many groups?

Comment: What version of django are you using ?

Comment: No a user can only be in one group. And I'm using Django 1.10.1

Answer (score 0):

You can have intermediate model called *Membership* to define the level of membership

models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # may be a relations to User here


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through=Membership)


class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    members = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    # member level
    is_leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

you can check the documention on [ManyToMany fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for some more examples.